# Increase thickness only on specific parts of a 3D model

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to improve the model shown below. As it can be  seen, the cloak of the model contains some holes. I tried to apply the Solidify modifier, but in this case the thickness of the whole model is affected (i.e. the neck of the model becomes to wide). Is there any way to fill these holes?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some modifiers have an option to affect only specific parts of a model defined by a **Vertex Group**.

The workflow is like this:

In **Edit Mode** select the vertices you want to affect, create a vertex group by pressing the **Plus Sign** on the right of Vertex groups.

Click then on **Assign** to make the selected vertices part of the newly created group.

[image: create vertex group]

To use the modifier on a specific vertex group, select it from the list available groups:

[image: select vertex group]

Vertices that are not part of that vertex group will not be affected by the modifier.

**NOTE**: If what you are missing are faces on the mesh, the solidify modifier will not fill those gaps. It will only make the surfaces of existing faces thicker.

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm this works for faces too, not just vertices. F.i. I selected all the faces around the edges of this jacket I made, and it thickened only those edges.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach would be to make the portion you wish to modify a separate object, at least temporarily.

In this example, if the cloak is not connected to the rest you can simply select one vertex and press L.   Press P and choose by selection.

If the cloak is connected you can also Press P and choose separate by Material.

You can then modify the parted object with ANY modifier as you like, and if you wish, apply the modifier and Join (Ctrl+J)