# Solidify: Give different thickness to specific faces

Tags: modifiers, 3d-printing

My model is made to be 3D printed. I found a weak spot where my cars always break.
I would like to give extra thickness on that spot (the selected faces you can see), and not to the whole model.
What would be the best way to solve it?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very similar to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14885/increase-thickness-only-on-specific-parts-of-a-3d-model), but the method is a tiny bit different.

Instead of setting only the weak part as your vertex group. Set every vertex of your model at 0.5 weight for instance and set the weak spot at 1. Then when you set the vertex group in the solidify modifier, the weak part will get 2 times more thick than the rest of the mesh. The weight is a direct multiplier to the solidify thickness.

Example in action :

[image]

Comment: Hello.
It works. Just a question about the solidify thickness.
If I set the Solidify thickness at 2mm, the whole model at a 0.5 vertex group weight and the weak spot at a 1 weight.
-Will I get 2mm thickness on the parts with 1 weight, and 1mm on the rest?

What I want is to have 2mm on the whole model and for example, let's say 4mm on the weak spot.
So, should I set the thickness at 4mm, in order to get 2mm on the whole model and 4 on the spot with weight of 1?
Thank you!

Comment: You will get 2 mm on the weak part and 1 mm on all the other parts if you do it that way, so to get your desird output you should set the solidify to 4mm. Keep in mind there will be an interpolation on the faces bordering the weak spot and the rest where the solidify jumps from 2 mm to 4mm. I think this is desirable in your case but if you want a straight jump from 2 to 4 consider adding an edge loop right next to the weak sport border and setting the weight to 0.5. Hope that was clear enough

Comment: Yes, it is clear now. Thanks so much for your help!
 -In short, for anyone interested: Parts with weight 1 will get the thickness set in solidify. Parts with 0.5 weight will get half the thickness.

Comment: You can also use weight painting to customize the gradient if you wish